# Run VBA on any PowerPoint to change the LanguageID

Tags: vbscript, powerpoint

I'm trying to create a toolbar with a button that will change the `LanguageID` for all shapes and text boxes in a PowerPoint document to EnglishUS. This is to fix a problem where if someone spell-checks a document using another language (in this instance, French), that language is embedded into the .ppt file itself. When another user tries to spell-check the same area using another language, say English, the words the spell checker suggests are in the original language. For instance, it tried to correct the word 'specified' to 'specifie', a French word. From what I've read, the only way to fix this language issue is with a VBscript, and the only way to run a VBscript in Powerpoint without embedding it into a .ppt and loading that file every time is by creating an add-in with a toolbar button to run the macro, also using VBS. Below is the code which I've taken from various sources, and when I tried to put it together, it didn't work (although it did compile). If someone could take a look, I'm sure its a simple syntax error or something like that, it would be a HUGE help. Thanks in advance!!

By the way if anyone knows an easier way to run a macro in PPT without having to open a certain PPT every time, I'm ALL ears.

and now, the script:

```
Sub Auto_Open() 
    Dim oToolbar As CommandBar 
     Dim oButton As CommandBarButton 
     Dim MyToolbar As String 

     ''# Give the toolbar a name 
     MyToolbar = "Fix Language" 

     On Error Resume Next    
     ''# so that it doesn't stop on the next line if the toolbar's already there 

     ''# Create the toolbar; PowerPoint will error if it already exists 
     Set oToolbar = CommandBars.Add(Name:=MyToolbar, _ 
         Position:=msoBarFloating, Temporary:=True) 
     If Err.Number <> 0 Then   
           ''# The toolbar's already there, so we have nothing to do 
           Exit Sub 
     End If 

     On Error GoTo ErrorHandler 

     ''# Now add a button to the new toolbar 
     Set oButton = oToolbar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton) 

     ''# And set some of the button's properties 
     With oButton 
          .DescriptionText = "Fix Language for Spell Check"    
           ''# Tooltip text when mouse if placed over button 
          .Caption = "Click to Run Script"     
          ''# Text if Text in Icon is chosen 
          .OnAction = "Button1"   
           ''# Runs the Sub Button1() code when clicked 
          .Style = msoButtonIcon     
           ''# Button displays as icon, not text or both 
          .FaceId = 59        

     End With 

     ''# Repeat the above for as many more buttons as you need to add 
     ''# Be sure to change the .OnAction property at least for each new button 

     ''# You can set the toolbar position and visibility here if you like 
     ''# By default, it'll be visible when created 
     oToolbar.Top = 150 
     oToolbar.Left = 150 
     oToolbar.Visible = True 

 NormalExit: 
     Exit Sub   ''# so it doesn't go on to run the errorhandler code 

 ErrorHandler: 
      ''# Just in case there is an error 
      MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description 
      Resume NormalExit: 
 End Sub 

 Sub Button1() 
 ''#         This is the code to replace the LanguageID throughout the ppt 
  Option Explicit    
  Public Sub ChangeSpellCheckingLanguage()    
  Dim j As Integer, k As Integer, scount As Integer, fcount As Integer  
  scount = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count  
  For j = 1 To scount  
  fcount = ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes.Count  
  For k = 1 To fcount  
  If ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes(k).HasTextFrame Then  
  ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes(k) _  
  .TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = msoLanguageIDEnglishUS  
  End If  
  Next k  
  Next j  
  End Sub 

  End Sub
```

Comment: Relates to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653183/vba-powerpoint-2013-change-presentation-language-including-smartart-objects

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite obvious if it is not clear yet.

As you can see the `sub Button1()` encapsulates another sub. Thus, I advise you to remove the call `ChangeSpellingCheckingLanguage` and the last `End sub`, then your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an incredibly late answer, but I just solved this problem using VBScript (which can be run outside of powerpoint). The script as written will change the language of each powerpoint file in a given directory (and subdirectories) to English. Here's the script:

```
Option Explicit

'microsoft office constants
Const msoTrue = -1
Const msoFalse = 0
Const msoLanguageIDEnglishUS = 1033
Const msoGroup = 6

'starting folder (current folder)
Const START_FOLDER = ".\"
'valid powerpoint file extensions
Dim FILE_EXTENSIONS : FILE_EXTENSIONS = Array("pptx", "pptm", "ppt", "potx", "potm", "pot")
'desired language for all Text
Dim DESIRED_LANGUAGE : DESIRED_LANGUAGE = msoLanguageIDEnglishUS

'VBScript file system objects for starting folder
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objStartingFolder : Set objStartingFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(START_FOLDER)

IterateContainingItems objStartingFolder

'recursive subroutine to iterate each file in specified folder and all subfolders
Sub IterateContainingItems(objCurrentFolder)
    Dim colFiles : Set colFiles = objCurrentFolder.Files
    Dim objCurrentFile
    For Each objCurrentFile in colFiles
        ReportInfo(objCurrentFile)
    Next
    Dim colFolders : Set colFolders = objCurrentFolder.SubFolders
    Dim objNextFolder
    For Each objNextFolder in colFolders
        IterateContainingItems objNextFolder
    Next
End Sub

'subroutine executed for every file iterated by IterateContainingItems subroutine
Sub ReportInfo(objCurrentFile)
    Dim strPathToFile
    strPathToFile = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(objCurrentFile.Path)

    If isPowerpointFile(strPathToFile) Then
        Dim objPowerpointApp, objPresentations, objPresentation, objSlides, intSlideCount

        set objPowerpointApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
        set objPresentations = objPowerpointApp.Presentations
        Set objPresentation = objPresentations.Open(strPathToFile, msoFalse, msoFalse, msoFalse)
        Set objSlides = objPresentation.Slides
        intSlideCount = objSlides.Count

        ResetLanguage objPresentation

        objPresentation.Save
        objPresentation.Close
        objPowerpointApp.Quit
    End If
End Sub

'check if given filepath specifies a powerpoint file as described by the "constant" extension array
Function isPowerpointFile(strFilePath)
    Dim strExtension, found, i
    strExtension = objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFilePath)
    found = false
    for i = 0 to ubound(FILE_EXTENSIONS)
        if FILE_EXTENSIONS(i) = strExtension then    
            found = true
            exit for
        end if
    next
    isPowerpointFile = found
End Function

'finds every shape in the entire document and attempts to reset its LanguageID
Sub ResetLanguage(objCurrentPresentation)
    Dim objShape

    'change shapes from presentation-wide masters
    If objCurrentPresentation.HasHandoutMaster Then
        For Each objShape in objCurrentPresentation.HandoutMaster.Shapes
            ChangeLanguage objShape
        Next
    End If
    If objCurrentPresentation.HasNotesMaster Then
        For Each objShape in objCurrentPresentation.NotesMaster.Shapes
            ChangeLanguage objShape
        Next
    End If
    If objCurrentPresentation.HasTitleMaster = msoTrue Then
        For Each objShape in objCurrentPresentation.TitleMaster.Shapes
            ChangeLanguage objShape
        Next
    End If
    'change shapes from each design's master
    Dim tempDesign
    For Each tempDesign in objCurrentPresentation.Designs
        For Each objShape in tempDesign.SlideMaster.Shapes
            ChangeLanguage objShape
        Next
    Next
    'change shapes from each slide
    Dim tempSlide
    For Each tempSlide in objCurrentPresentation.Slides
        For Each objShape in tempSlide.Shapes
            ChangeLanguage objShape
        Next
        If tempSlide.hasNotesPage Then
            For Each objShape in tempSlide.NotesPage.Shapes
                ChangeLanguage objShape
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub

'if the given shape contains a text element, it checks and corrects the LanguageID
'if the given shape is a group, it iterates through each element in the group
Sub ChangeLanguage(objShape)
    If objShape.Type = msoGroup Then
        Dim objShapeGroup : Set objShapeGroup = objShape.GroupItems
        Dim objShapeChild
        For Each objShapeChild in objShapeGroup
            ChangeLanguage objShapeChild
        Next
    Else
        If objShape.HasTextFrame Then
            Dim intOrigLanguage : intOrigLanguage = objShape.TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID
            If Not intOrigLanguage = DESIRED_LANGUAGE Then
                If objShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Length = 0 Then
                    objShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "[PLACEHOLDER_TEXT_TO_DELETE]"
                End If
                objShape.TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = DESIRED_LANGUAGE
                If objShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "[PLACEHOLDER_TEXT_TO_DELETE]" Then
                    objShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ""
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

To run it, just copy and paste the code into a text editor and save it as "script_name.vbs" in the directory with your powerpoint files. Run it by double clicking the script and waiting.

Answer (score 0):

To load a macro every time PowerPoint is opened, you will want to create a PowerPoint AddIn. Microsoft has provided step-by-step guide for [Office XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140944%28v=office.10%29.aspx). For Office 2007 and newer, AFAIK the following steps will do that:

- Save file as *.ppam into the directory it suggests (`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\AddIns`)
- Open the Settings (click the office button in the top left corner and select "PowerPoint Options"), select the "Add-Ins" page, choose "PowerPoint Add-Ins" in the drop-down behind "Manage" and click the "Go" button. A dialog opens. Selecting "Add New" brings up a file picker dialog. You should be able to select the file there.

You can also use the [Office Custom UI Editor](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/08/07/7293.aspx) to create ribbons.

However, I have already created such a Language Fixer Add-In for current versions of PowerPoint, and I have put it up for free download for personal use: [PowerPoint Language Fixer by Jan Schejbal](http://www.janschejbal.de/projekte/languagefixer/)