# VBA Powerpoint 2013: change presentation language including SmartArt objects

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I can not find a way to change by VBA script the language in SmartArt objects in Powerpoint 2013.
I've seen [PowerPoint 2007 - Set language on tables, charts etc that contains text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735765/powerpoint-2007-set-language-on-tables-charts-etc-that-contains-text) but it does not work for SmartArt objects.
Any idea how I could do this?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [code](https://gist.github.com/tdalon/4633be11ca2241c983fa1645400a22b1) I finally use to change the language including SmartArts:

```
Sub SetLangUS()
  Call changeLanguage(ActivePresentation, "US")
End Sub

Sub SetLangDE()
  Call changeLanguage(ActivePresentation, "DE")
End Sub



Private Function changeLanguage(oPres As Presentation, langStr As String)
' Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735765/powerpoint-2007-set-language-on-tables-charts-etc-that-contains-text
' https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245468

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim r, c As Integer
    Dim oSlide As Slide
    Dim oNode As SmartArtNode
    Dim oShape, oNodeShape As Shape
    Dim lang As String

    'lang = "Norwegian"
    'Determine language selected
    If langStr = "US" Then
        lang = msoLanguageIDEnglishUS
    ElseIf langStr = "UK" Then
        lang = msoLanguageIDEnglishUK
    ElseIf langStr = "DE" Then
        lang = msoLanguageIDGerman
    ElseIf langStr = "FR" Then
        lang = msoLanguageIDFrench
    End If

    'Set default language in application
    oPres.DefaultLanguageID = lang

    'Set language in each textbox in each slide
    For Each oSlide In oPres.Slides
        For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
            'Check first if it is a table
            If oShape.HasTable Then
                For r = 1 To oShape.Table.Rows.Count
                    For c = 1 To oShape.Table.Columns.Count
                        oShape.Table.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = lang
                    Next
                Next
            ElseIf oShape.HasSmartArt Then
                For Each oNode In oShape.SmartArt.AllNodes
                    oNode.TextFrame2.TextRange.LanguageID = lang
                Next
            Else
                oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = lang

                    For c = 0 To oShape.GroupItems.Count - 1
                        oShape.GroupItems(c).TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = lang
                    Next

            End If
        Next
    Next

    ' Update Masters
    For Each oShape In oPres.SlideMaster.Shapes
        oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = lang
    Next

    For Each oShape In oPres.TitleMaster.Shapes
        oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = lang
    Next

    For Each oShape In oPres.NotesMaster.Shapes
        oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = lang
    Next

    ' MsgBox
    MsgBox "Presentation Language was changed to " & langStr & ".", vbOKOnly, "SetLanguage"


End Function
```

Comment: Is there a reason why a shape can't include both a table and SmartArt?

Comment: @Leo  PPT just doesn't work that way.  When you insert a table, for example the whole table is a shape whose .HasTable property is True and whose .Table property returns the table itself.  Peculiar, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the Nodes (or GroupItems) of the SmartArt object like this:

```
Sub SwitchSmartArtLanguage(oSA As SmartArt)
  Dim oNode As SmartArtNode
  With oSA
    For Each oNode In .Nodes
      oNode.TextFrame2.TextRange.LanguageID = msoLanguageIDEnglishUK
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work. How did you come to TextFrame2 instead of TextFrame for normal shapes? Would  I need to recurse through the nodes? I will post my code later.

Comment: Strange. It worked in my test deck. I use TextFrame2 (and TextRange2 and various other V2 APIs) as they add more properties to objects since Office 2007 and since you mentioned you are using 2013 it makes sense to use the latest API. Yes you need to recurse through the nodes as per the example above.

Comment: Your code only replaces the root nodes and not the children nodes below the first one. Replacing For Each oNode In .Nodes by For Each oNode In .AllNodes works. :-)